# mysql join query that needs to return negative set

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose i have 2 tables for user & task. have user_id & status in task with status having possible values "complete" & "not complete".
Now I want to retrieve users who have not completed even 1 task. 
The most crude way is to first find users who have atleast 1 complete task and run a "not in" query.

Any better ways to achieve this without an "in" subquery. Please note that the data set is huge and i can't afford to have a lock on the task table for long time!

Comment: can you please give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: user(id,name) has records (1,"a"),(2,"b"), (3,"c")

Comment: sorry for incomplete commment. task(id, user_id, status). user 1 has 2 tasks - 1 complete and 2 not complete. users 2,3 have all in-complete tasks. the query should return users 2,3 as the result. hope this clarifies it!

Comment: all record on task are for all users? or a specific user can have specific task/

Comment: @KCore See my answer fiddle for task completed users http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb24d/2   fiddle for users that have not completed task  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb24d/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tasks t
    WHERE t.user_id = u.user_id
    AND t.status = 'complete'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

When `task.user_id` cannot contain NULL (i.e. has a `NOT NULL` constraint), `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` is your [best choice](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24888):

```
SELECT user.* FROM user
LEFT JOIN task ON (task.user_id = user.id AND task.status = 'complete')
WHERE task.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  below query will list the users that have completed even 1 task or more than 1

```
SELECT u.*,
COUNT(  CASE WHEN  t.`status`= 'Completed' THEN t.`status` END  ) AS completed ,

COUNT(  CASE WHEN  t.`status`= 'Not completed' THEN t.`status` END  ) AS Not_completed

FROM `user`  u

LEFT JOIN `task` t  ON (u.id =t.user_id)

GROUP BY t.user_id HAVING completed >0
```

And this will list the users those who haven't  completed even 1 task

```
SELECT u.*,
COUNT(  CASE WHEN  t.`status`= 'Completed' THEN t.`status` END  ) AS completed ,

COUNT(  CASE WHEN  t.`status`= 'Not completed' THEN t.`status` END  ) AS Not_completed

FROM `user`  u

LEFT JOIN `task` t  ON (u.id =t.user_id)

GROUP BY t.user_id HAVING completed = 0
```

[**See fiddle for task completed users**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb24d/2)

[**See fiddle for users that have not completed task**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb24d/3)

Comment: In your second query i think it would be best if you had HAVING completed = 0. The way you have it, you only show the users who have incomplete tasks. And you probably should also group by u.id, to make sure that you get the users that have no records in the tasks table

Comment: took >5 mins to return result. not going to cut it

Comment: @FilipeSilva `HAVING completed = 0` will not  work perfectly  hence i am taking count there can be multiple tasks against the one user so i have to check the not completed part should be > 0 and your second point of group by i agree with you there will be id from user table

Comment: @KCore make sure you have properly indexed your columns

Comment: @dianuj. OP said "I want to retrieve users who have not completed even 1 task". I think that is HAVING completed = 0, If you look for NOT_COMPLETED > 0, you can let pass a guy that has 100 completed and 1 NOT_COMPLETED, wich you don't want

Comment: @FilipeSilva yup that makes sense i agree with your point :) But this i am leaving on OP's end to use `HAVING` according to its need